# Question about Public Inner Classes

Tags: java, oop, class, inner-classes

I have gone through various questions about public inner classes in this forum, however I didn't see any answer for what I am trying to find, so yet again another question about Java Public Inner Classes. I am reviewing another developer's code and this person has made use of a lot of inner classes. Here's an example

```
    public class A{
              private class B
              private class C
              private class D
              :
              :

    public class B{
    }

    public class c{
    }

    public class D{
    }
}
```

So when I asked the developer about why she used inner classes, she told me, since these classes are going to be ONLY used by this class, she did it this way, which I agree is a valid reason,

However the class has become a "long" (around 200 lines of getters and setters including 4-5 class definitions) class, with bunch of inner classes. Though I agree with her reason, I am concerned about the length of the class. I almost feel like telling her to remove the inner classes and make them classes of their own, but for now, the only advantage of doing this is it reduces the size of the class.

I personally avoid using inner classes, it might just be a habit or I am just dogmatic when it comes to this, so I don't want my personal bias to dictate the review. That's why, I would like to know from you guys, what other advantages or disadvantages are there of what I am proposing? (i.e. move them to their own classes) Thanks.

Comment: are these inner classes public -- as stated in the question's title and the question body itself -- or private, like in the code example?

Comment: Yes, the code is like what I have in the code sample. The reason for calling these inner classes public, is because the class definition itself is public

Comment: the outer class is public, but it hides the private inner classes.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what about the inner "public" class definitions, would they be made "public" so external classes can access these classes through getters?

Comment: I ran a test program and it proved my above assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I know is that inner classes can access *private instance* variables of the outer class. The use of private inner classes prevents access from other classes, too.

From [oracle java tutorial:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> Logical grouping of classes—If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.
>
> Increased encapsulation—Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.
>
> More readable, maintainable code—Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason of having an inner class (do not be confused with static inner classes) is to reduce the visibility of `B`, `C` and `D`, maybe collecting all classes in the same package and using *package private* visibility modifier (i.e. no modifier at all) would be enough?

```
package com.example

public class A {
}

class B {
}

class c {
}

class D {
}
```

Now only class `A` is available throughout the whole project, while `B`, `C` and `D` are only available within `com.example` package. Please remember that using inner classes comes with a price of storing additional implicit `this` reference to parent class (`A` in this example).

Comment: what if classes B, C or D is returned as by a getter method? Would there be accessibility issues?

Comment: Interesting question. If you return `B` from let's say `A.getB()`, you can still call this method from another package, but you cannot have a variable of type `B` and assign the result to it (this is possible within `com.example` package.

Comment: What I am understanding is that if B had a "public" method "getB1", I could do this "A.getB().getB1()", but couldn't do "B varB = A.getB()"

Comment: I just wrote a test program, and it proved my comment above. Basically if the class definitions are non-public there will be accessibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with that if the inner classes are only going to be used in the outer class and wont be used anywhere outside. Maybe formatting can be changed to make it easy to read/maintainable if not done already